# How to merge two tables based on rows and columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

```
df1 <- data.frame(MLID=c('992','992','BJR'),
              Position=c('N0','N1','N1'),
              Weight=c(0.125,0.58,0.69))


df2 <- data.frame(MLID=c('992','992','992','992',
                     'BJR','BJR','BJR','BJR'),
              Weight=c(0,0.251,0.501,1.001,
                       0,0.251,0.501,1.001),
              N0=c(2.80,4.05,4.05,4.05,
                   4.05,4.05,4.05,4.05),
              N1=c(3.47,4.73,4.95,5.15,
                   4.73,7.73,4.95,5.15) )
```

What I want is merge this two tables follow the rules:

1. the MLID
2. Look at position(Its N0 or N1)
3. Find the range where the weight sits in (like the approximately vlookup in excel)(2.8 means charge for weight (0,0.250) for 992 N0, 4.05 for weight (0.251,0.500) for 992 N0,3.47 for weight (0,0.250) 992 N1 etc.

So the final output should be :

```
MILD  Position  Weight  Charge
992      N0     0.125    2.8
992      N1     0.580    4.95
BJR      N1     0.690    4.95
```

Is it possible do it in R? especially in dplyr package?

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setnames(melt(setDT(df2), measure = c("NO", "N1"), variable.name = "Position", value.name = "Charge"), "Weight", "wt")[df1, on = .(MLID, Position, wt <= Weight), mult = "last"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option using `data.table` `rolling` join can be achieved. First, `df2` needs to be transformed in `long-format` using `melt` and then join both `df1` and `df2`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1, key = c("MLID", "Position","Weight") )

df2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = c("MLID","Weight"), variable.name = "Position", 
                                                      value.name = "Charge")

setDT(df2, key = c("MLID", "Position","Weight"))

df2[df1, roll = "nearest"]
#    MLID Weight Position Charge
# 1:  992  0.580       N1   4.95
# 2:  992  0.125       NO   2.80
# 3:  BJR  0.690       N1   4.95
```

**Option#2:** A `tidyverse` based approach can be as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% gather(Position, Charge, -MLID, -Weight) %>%
  right_join(df1, by=c("MLID", "Position")) %>%
  filter(Weight.x <= Weight.y) %>%
  group_by(MLID, Position) %>%
  arrange(Weight.y-Weight.x) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  select(MLID, Weight = Weight.y, Position, Charge)

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups: MLID, Position [3]
#   MLID  Weight Position Charge
#   <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 992    0.580 N1         4.95
# 2 992    0.125 NO         2.80
# 3 BJR    0.690 N1         4.95
```

**Data:**

The `OP's` data is slightly modified to include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in `data.frame` in order to avoid unnecessary warnings.

```
df1 <- data.frame(MLID=c('992','992','BJR'),
                  Position=c('NO','N1','N1'),
                  Weight=c(0.125,0.58,0.69), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- data.frame(MLID=c('992','992','992','992',
                         'BJR','BJR','BJR','BJR'),
                  Weight=c(0,0.251,0.501,1.001,
                           0,0.251,0.501,1.001),
                  NO=c(2.80,4.05,4.05,4.05,
                       4.05,4.05,4.05,4.05),
                  N1=c(3.47,4.73,4.95,5.15,
                       4.73,7.73,4.95,5.15), stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never touch data.table before. The `rolling join` here seems like only select the nearest value. Let me make it clear. The charge on the same row with the weight,like 4.95 for N1 BJR Weight 0.501,this means 4.95 for weight in the range(0.501,1.001) on N1 BJR. Based on your answer, if last input of weight in `df1` change from 0.69 to 0.88, your output will go to next charge level rather than stay in the charge for (0.501,1.001)

Comment: @DingruiZhang There are many options with `roll`. I have used "nearest" but  you can try using `roll = TRUE' which is last value carried forward. Or `-Inf` for next value carried backward.

Answer (score 2):

We could use a non-equi join with `data.table`.  Reshape the second dataset to 'long' format with `melt` and join with the first data on "MLID", "Position" and the non-equi comparison on the "Weight' columns and assign the `last` value of 'Charge' to create the column in 'df1'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setnames(melt(setDT(df2), measure = c("NO", "N1"), 
       variable.name = "Position", value.name = "Charge"), "Weight", "wt"), 
      Charge := Charge, on = .(MLID, Position, Weight > wt), mult = "last"] 

df1
#   MLID Position Weight Charge
#1:  992       NO  0.125   2.80
#2:  992       N1  0.580   4.95
#3:  BJR       N1  0.690   4.95
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the results for this example using `melt()` but I was able to convert to long format using `gather(Position, Charge, -MLID, -Weight)`, then the code worked: `df2 <- df2 %>% gather(Position, Charge, -MLID, -Weight)


setDT(df1)[setnames(df2,"Weight", "wt"), 
           Charge := Charge, on = .(MLID, Position, Weight > wt), mult = "last"] 
df1`. Just can't follow why "wt" was used.

Comment: @TheSciGuy  This was posted on 2018.  May be there is some changes in the version

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R version:

```
outdf <- merge(df1, df2, by = "MLID")
outdf$dist <- abs(outdf$Weight.x - outdf$Weight.y)
ting <- aggregate(dist ~ MLID + Position, FUN = function(x) min(x), data = outdf)
outdf2 <- merge(outdf, ting, by.x = c("MLID", "Position", "dist"))
outdf2$charge <- ifelse(outdf2$Position == "N1", outdf2$N1, outdf2$NO)
outdf2 <- outdf2[,c("MLID", "Position", "Weight.x", "charge")]
outdf2
# MLID Position Weight.x charge
# 1  992       N1    0.580   4.95
# 2  992       NO    0.125   2.80
# 3  BJR       N1    0.690   4.95
```

Answer (score 0):

```
joined_df <- merge(data1, data2, by.x = "column key name in data1", 
         by.y = "column key name in data2", all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```